# Returning the form in form_alter function

Tags: 7, webforms

I have a doubt that is, can i use `return $form;` in `hook_form_alter` function. When i used some callback function inside the form, its not calling to that particular function. Thatsy i confused whether the form is returning or not.

i tried this thing but its not calling to custom_form_reset function

```
function cap_academy_contactus_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
       if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_860'){
        $form['actions']['reset'] = array(
          '#type' => 'submit',
          '#value' => t('Reset fields'),
          '#submit' => array('contact_form_reset'),
          '#prefix' => '<div class="contactform">',
                '#suffix' => '</div>'   
        );
        return $form;
      }
    }

    function contact_form_reset($form, &$form_state){
      $form_state['rebuild'] = FALSE;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it, sure. But it won't do anything.

The `$form` is passed by reference, precisely so that it can be altered in-place. Core never does anything with the return value from form alters, so there isn't much point doing it.

Your code looks right, put a `drupal_set_message`/`dpm` in the submit handler to confirm whether it's actually being called or not, or whether it's your one-liner that's not doing what you're expecting.